# Issue with index not outputting even though it shows in the list

Tags: python, indexing, web-scraping, scrapy

I am web scraping a site to get item specs. For some reason I am not able to pull a certain spec for some item even though its on the site.

When I output the item's spec's xpath text, the index I want to pull shows, `'<td>\nColor\n</td>',`

Here is how I am going about it all.

Pull all the specs for said item:

```
item_specs = response.xpath("//tr[@class='trSpecSheetRow' and not(@hidden)]/td/text()").getall()
```

Get the spec I want by finding it with .index

```
item_color = item_specs.index('\nColor\n')
```

Get the spec info

```
item_specB = item_specs[item_color + 1]
```

Then I just yield it as the spec name with the info.

```
yield {'item_color': item_specB'}
```

What is going wrong? Also, hope I explained well enough!

https://pastebin.com/vgSaiawq

Comment: Could you be more specific about "not outputting"? What value are you getting for `item_color` and`item_specB`?

Comment: Difficult to tell without a URL or the site's HTML source. This is lacking information overall. My guess, as is often the case with these questions, is that the elements you're looking for a dynamically created, which means BeautifulSoup and Requests alone are not sufficient.

Comment: first check if page doesn't use JavaScript to add item - `scrapy` can't run JavaScript (the same as `BeautifulSoup` and `Requests`) and you may need `Selenium` to control web server which can run JavaScript. It should be even extension `scrapy-selenium`.

Comment: nothing, an error. And the element didnt change if the xpath works.

Comment: I don't see these classes in page source.

Answer (score 0):

So the \n was messing with my outputting to a csv file. I fixed it with the following:

```
    def cleaner(self, value, character_remove):
       cleaned_output = value.strip(character_remove)
       return cleaned_output
```

and adding this to my spec variables:

```
        try:
            item_heightstyle = item_specs.index('\nHeight Style\n')
            item_specA = self.cleaner(item_specs[item_heightstyle + 1], '\n')
        except:
            item_specA = 'N/A'
```